# Android: How to use an existing C++ static library from your JNI code?

Tags: android, c++, java-native-interface, static-libraries

I've seen questions similar to this one, but the scenarios are not exactly the same, nor can I get an answer that works on my problem.

I have the source code for a C++ library. We need to use this library as part of an android application but it also needs to be available for third party to use as a C++ library.

I have a makefile that generates the .a file out of the library's source code, using ndk's compiler. That's the pure C++ part.

On the Java part, I have a simple demo project with a simple activity containing a button. When the button is pressed a call to native code is made.

Everything works fine as long as I don't try to call a function from the library from the JNI function.

Here are the sources for the library:

**SimpleMath.h**

```
int Add(int aNumber1, int aNumberB);
```

**SimpleMath.cpp**

```
#include "SimpleMath.h"

int Add(int aNumberA, int aNumberB)
{
  return aNumberA + aNumberB;
}
```

The **makefile**

```
APP      = simple_app
LIBRARY  = simple_library.a
OBJECTS  = SimpleMath.o
CFLAGS   = -Wall -pedantic
NDK_PATH = /home/jug/perforce/jug_navui_personal_main/Env/Linux/Android/ndk/r7c
CXX      = $(NDK_PATH)/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++
AR       = $(NDK_PATH)/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ar
SYSTEM_LIBS = -lstdc++ -lm
INCLUDE_PATH += ${NDK_PATH}/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/usr/include

all: $(LIBRARY)

$(LIBRARY): 
    $(CXX) -c SimpleMath.c
    $(AR) rcs simple_library.a SimpleMath.o

clean:
    rm *.o *.a
```

On the java side, these are the files:

**hello-jni.c**

```
#include <string.h>
#include <jni.h>

#include "../../../native/simple_library/SimpleMath.h"

jstring Java_com_amstapps_samples_draft08jni_MainActivity_helloJni(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj)
{
    // Uncommenting the line below results in undefined-symbol compile error
    //int d = Add(1, 2);

    return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "Hello from JNI!");
}
```

**Android.mk**

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := my_simple_library
LOCAL_ARM_MODE := arm
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ../../../native/simple_library/simple_library.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)
#include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS    := eng
LOCAL_ARM_MODE       := arm
#LOCAL_PRELINK_MODULE := false
LOCAL_MODULE         := hello-jni
LOCAL_SRC_FILES      := hello-jni.c
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES     := ../../../android/native/simple_library
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := my_simple_library
#LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES := my_simple_library
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

**Application.mk**

```
APP_MODULES := my_simple_library hello-jni
```

As I said, the problem comes when I to actually make use of the functionality in the library from the jni native code in java application.

Now, I'm not longer sure whether my problem is in the static-library's makefile or on the Android.mk. I first thought it must have to do with the generation of the library itself, but at this point, after seeing there are so many options I didn't know about in Android.mk,  I have to admit I have no clue.

What else..?

Oh, yes, I also noticed my pure C++ library is using cpp extension whereas the jni code in java project is using c extension. I tried to have the latter using cpp as well, but compiler complains. Could this be part of the problem?

The error code that I get when trying to compile the Android.mk file is "undefined symbol", so, is the list of functions in simple_library.a (there's actually 1 function) not visible to hello-jni.c because of it being C++ and not plain C?

Another thing you might notice is I'm trying to build the static library on its own makefile as opposed to generating it with Android.mk; there's a reason for that, but at this point I would also be happy if I had to have it in generated by Android.mk if that's what it takes.

I don't see any way to add an attachment in here so that to share a zip with the project.
Let me know if there's something I'm missing.. Otherwise the code is in a depot in bitbucket, so I can easily share it with anyone having an account there too.

Thanks for you answers.

Comment: Are you able to generate "so" file ??? Follow this http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/49.html

Comment: "_I tried to have the latter using cpp as well, but compiler complains_" specifically about what? @Viktor response, while being 100% technically correct, might not be applicable if you intend to be serious with the **c++** on your library.

Comment: I do intent to be serious on C++, so I'm afraid his solution is not good enough. It's not his fault, I guess the sample C++ code was as simple as in not using any C++ specific feature.

Comment: You could use [JavaCPP](http://code.google.com/p/javacpp/) to simplify all that. Let me know if you need an answer for your specific use case...

Answer (score 7):

You write a lot of correct things, but you're missing just one.

The function's name gets mangled in C++. And in the .so file you do not get "Add" symbol, but something like "Add@8i". To avoid mangling just use the

```
extern "C" int Add(int x, int y)
```

declaration in the .cpp file and in the .h.

Usually one also adds the

```
/// Some .h file
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

/// Your usual C-like declarations go here

#ifdef __cplusplus
} // extern "C"
#endif
```

And the

```
extern "C"
```

for each of the exported functions in the .cpp file.

Comment: With all respect to correctness of this reply, the OP is talking about availability to 3rd party as **c++** library. So he might want to use some c++ powers and then he will miss the mangling pretty soon.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. This is the only true problem I've spotted. The OP gets an "unresolved symbol" while using the Add() function. I only mention that the Add isn't visible to the jni's C file. To fix that and only that issue all he needs to do is to add the extern "C" modifier. It only concerns the Add function (and the like), there's no need to avoid using C++.

Comment: Hi guys, thank you all for posting. I followed advice in answer number 1 (use of extern keyword) and it works like charm. I'm now able to build the JNI shared library either by 1) Generating the static library as part of tasks in Android.mk, and 2) Using a pre-compiled library, which was the preferred option. My only concern is the one spotted by Viktor. Sample library is very simple, but in the real thing I'll need to use C++. I'll add some C++ functionality and see what error (if any) do I get.